# Appending to map with set<size_t> in it

Tags: c++, hashmap

Hey my  mentor(kinda) gave me this task  and i am having trouble   solving it .

So basically i am getting `const vector<string> &data`  full of string and i need to check their place, like where are they  in that vector so here is an example:

getting an input with: `data={"chair","desk","table","chair","chair","desk"}`

my output should be:`{"chair" ->{0,3,4},"desk"->{1,5} , "table"->{2}}`

so what i did is :

```
 map<string, set<size_t>> index(const vector<string> & data) noexcept {
    
        map<string, set<size_t>> res;  // thats gon be my return
       
        if (data.empty()){
            return res;
        }
        for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
         
           if(res.find(*it)==res.end()){


            //so basically when we are the first ,  and nothing is there so 
            // it should insert  for example =chair , and a 0 


                res.insert(std::make_pair(*it, 0));   // i tried it like that it doesnt work 
           }else{
                // when the string "chair is already in there  i want to append to the set  the current index where we are and thats what i dont know how
    
    
    
        }
}

    return res;
}
```

how to get the index  of the current string and append it to my set<size_t>  so that is works as mentioned?

Comment: You forgot to say what's wrong with your code.

Comment: i am asking for advice  there is nothing wrong with my code ineed help on how to implement this task to my code ,  how to get the index  of the current string and append it to my set<size_t>

Comment: what index? The position in the vector?

Comment: yess,  thats what i meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this quite easily by using an index-based loop:

```
map<string, set<size_t>> index(const vector<string> & data) 
{    
    map<string, set<size_t>> res; 

    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < data.size(); ++i)
        res[ data[i] ].insert(i);
      //    ^string^          ^index

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `decltype(data.size())` ? why that?

Comment: @MICHAEL Good, I'm glad :) Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem, when you're allowed to accept it.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Just to be completely sure that the types match up. Generally not an issue, but no harm in it. It's also nice to be explicit about what type one wants exactly.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Of course, the *correct* way would be to use a range library, or write some code that lets one write `for (auto [i, elem] : data)` and avoid mucking around with index types :)

Comment: Nah, we know what `vector::size` basically always returns; just have `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)` and stop confusing everybody needlessly!

Comment: ok, I have to admit that I wasnt aware that `std::vector::size_type` is only "usually" `size_t`. Your usage of "explicit about what type ... exactly" is a bit funny, but I get what you mean

Comment: It's never going to be wider than `size_t` though, so why bother? And, in practice, we're talking about like six elements here so c'mon

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Wait, is that guaranteed. I thought it's implementation defined what unsigned type `.size()` returns.

Comment: its not guaranteed but whatever it is, it fits in a `size_t`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Hmm, I didn't know that. I'll take your word for it now, but I'm going to look into that later :)

Comment: you could at least use `std::vector<string>::size_type`, thats less confusing

Comment: @cigien Name a built-in unsigned integer type wider than `std::size_t`. I'll wait.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Well, that's a style thing. I actually like `decltype` more because it expresses the intent clearly, i.e. I want exactly this type I'll be using to compare with. Also, one can't misspell the type that way.

Comment: Think about what `std::size_t` means, and about how many elements you could ever fit in a vector or array or other container.

Comment: Also this conversation has already taken more time for more people than this "trick" will ever save

Comment: fwiw, `std::vector<string>::size_type` is also what is recommended by [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)  for loop counters

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Hmm, that's true. `size_t` should always be large enough.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Well, yes, it's still exactly `std::vector<string>::size_type`,  `decltype` is just a different way to spell it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::set<size_t>> index(const std::vector<std::string>& data) noexcept 
{
    std::map<std::string, std::set<size_t>> res;
    for (size_t idx = 0u; idx < data.size(); idx++) 
    {
        res[data[idx]].insert(idx);
    }
    return res;        
}

int main()
{
   const std::vector<std::string> data={"chair","desk","table","chair","chair","desk"};
   auto map = index(data);

   for( auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it )
   {
      std::cout << (*it).first << " ->";
      for( auto it_id = (*it).second.begin(); it_id != (*it).second.end(); it_id++)
      {
        std::cout << " " << *it_id;
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

So your problem can be solved with a oneline as seen in the index function - but why ?

There is a reason youre getting all these different std container types as input - each of them have some guarantees as can be looked up in the documentation.

vector elements are continous in memory (sequence container).

while map and set are associative and have unique keys.

Consult the documentation for container properties (i linked to the vector - but the rest are also present in the tree to the left).
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

***The lesson is knowing which tool(container) to use to solve specific tasks***

And once you have that nailed .. making sure items are unique or how to sequence every odd element in a vector should be a breeze.